# where do i get the value of the hex color from this jquery plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, colors, hex

im using this jquery plugin which is a colorpicker, but i was wondering when the user chooses the color, where is the color hex value stored, so i can process it and put it in the database. thanks

this is the link for the jquery plugin:
http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

HTML

```
<div id='colourPicker'></div>
```

JS

```
$('#colourPicker').ColorPicker({
  onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb){
    $("#full").css("background-color", '#' + hex);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your code working? The value is not saved anywhere unless you do it inside the `onChange` function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in the `hex` argument included in the onchange event.  The one *you are already using.*

```
$('#colourPicker').ColorPicker({
    onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {

        // communicate with server here, probably with $.ajax
        // and save the hex argument.

        // Alternatively, you could set the value of a hidden input
        // here and submit a form afterward.

        $("#full").css("background-color", '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

#### Example of setting a hidden input value

HTML

```
<input id="hiddenHex" name="hiddenHex" type="hidden" value="" />
```

JS/jQuery

```
$('#hiddenHex').val(hex);
```

Comment: This. (Out of votes) the line in the source code looks like this: `    cal.data('colorpicker').onChange.apply(cal, [col, HSBToHex(col), HSBToRGB(col)]);      ` the code above should already work perfectly

Comment: In this case `hex` is an **argument** that is passed in into the event handler. Saying that it is a variable could confuse some people, since variables have another meaning in JavaScript (variables are members that are declared using a VariableStatement).

Comment: thanks for the great answer, how would i store in a hidden input field, that solution would be good becuase i need to change the colors of more than one thing, thanks :)) +1 up vote from me